# Swift - one method 2 classes

Tags: swift, swift-protocols

How in Swift apply one method to 2 different classes?

```
class Class1 {
      func doSomething() {
        self.doSomethingOnClass()
      }
}

   class Class2 {
      func doSomething() {
        self.doSomethingOnClass()
      }
}
```

so basically what I want to do instead of implementing the same method on each class I want to extract method and then ask it to treat self as Class1 or Class2. I hope protocols can do but looks like that if class implement protocol, then I have to write implementation to each class anyway.
Any advice what is best practice to achieve this? Or simply the best was is to implement it within a class even if it means duplicate code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are essentially two ways to do this: inheritance or protocols.  Swift definitely favors the latter, and inheritance is definitely a poor choice if only one function is involved.

Here's how to accomplish this using a protocol:

```
protocol CommonFunc: class {
    func doSomethingOnClass()
}

extension CommonFunc {
    func doSomethingOnClass() {
        print(type(of: self))
    }
}

class A: CommonFunc {

}

class B: CommonFunc {

}

A().doSomethingOnClass() // A
B().doSomethingOnClass() // B
```

Comment: As the message indicates, you can't.  You can define properties that the conformers have to implement, but you can't provide default implementations, unless you want them to be computed properties.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using protocols and extensions. Here's an example made using Playgrounds. You can copy and paste this code into a playground to tinker with it if you like, note that the extended protocol provides a default implementation for both classes and structs alike.

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import UIKit

protocol ClassProtocol {
    func classMethod()
}

extension ClassProtocol {
    func classMethod() {
        print("here i am")
    }
}

class Class1: ClassProtocol { }

class Class2: ClassProtocol { }

struct Struct1: ClassProtocol { }

Class1().classMethod()
Class2().classMethod()
Struct1().classMethod()
```

Output:

```
here i am
here i am
here i am
```

What's happening here? The protocol defines that the method `classMethod` is required in any object or struct using the protocol. Then the extension provides a default implementation for that method. You could also override this default implementation if necessary.

```
struct Struct2: ClassProtocol {
    func classMethod() {
        print("this does something different")
    }
}

Struct2().classMethod()
```

Output:

```
this does something different
```